# Javascript Array Manipulation - complex JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

example an object array is sent by the server -

```
var x = [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:[{f:6,g:7}],e:[{h:8}]},
    {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:[{f:6,g:7}],e:[{h:8}]},
    {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:[{f:6,g:7}],e:[{h:8}]}];
```

how do I alter it so it looks like this -

```
var y = [{a:1,b:2,c:3,h:8},{f:6,g:7,h:8},
     {a:1,b:2,c:3,h:8},{f:6,g:7,h:8},
     {a:1,b:2,c:3,h:8},{f:6,g:7,h:8}];
```

I've tried this ugly code just now -

```
function arrange(arr){
 var temp1 = [];
 var temp2 = [];
 var output = [];

   for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
     temp1 = arr[i].d;
     temp2 = arr[i].e;
     temp1.push(temp2[0].h);

     output.push(arr[i].a,arr[i].b,arr[i].c,temp2[0].h);
     output.push(temp1);

     return output;
  }
}
```

The output is wrong and only gives me the values, I need the key/value pair.

I want to send the correct response to the View. I'm working in a different kinda job at the moment and studying programming is what I do on the side. Right now, I'm stuck. Please forgive the horrible code :).

Comment: Is the nesting only ever 1 level deep, or can it be arbitrary?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Hello Evan, for the first view I want to hit, the nesting is only 1 level. For the other one it is arbitrary, maybe 2-3 levels.

Comment: Also, why is h: 8 included in the original block, is that intended?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli yes that is intended :)

Comment: So what is the generic rule there? The "e" keys are placed in both the first and second list, but the "d" keys are only placed in the second?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Yes. "e" goes to first Object. "d" together with "e" becomes another Object with key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript explicitly provides for destructured expressions: a very concise way to extract the the data into objects that you desired.

```
let result = x.reduce((elts, {a, b, c, d: [{f, g}], e: [{h}]}) => {
  return elts.concat({a, b, c, h}, {f, g, h})
}, [])
```

If you `console.log` the variable `result`, you'll find it gives your desired values in `y`:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"h":8},{"f":6,"g":7,"h":8},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"h":8},{"f":6,"g":7,"h":8},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"h":8},{"f":6,"g":7,"h":8}]
```

Comment: I should be reading JS docs on MDN. Thanks a lot! And yeah I made a mistake that I was creating an array instead of an object :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating arrays.  You want to create objects.

```
output = [];
for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
    var obj = {
        a: arr[i].a,
        b: arr[i].b,
        c: arr[i].c,
        h: arr[i].e.h
    }

    var obj2 = {
        f: arr[i].d.f,
        g: arr[i].d.g,
        h: arr[i].e.h
    }


    output.push(obj);
    output.push(obj2);
}
return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Changes to your attempt are commented:

```
var x = [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:[{f:6,g:7}],e:[{h:8}]},
    {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:[{f:6,g:7}],e:[{h:8}]},
    {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:[{f:6,g:7}],e:[{h:8}]}];

function arrange(arr){
  var temp1, temp2, output = [];

  for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
    temp1 = arr[i].d[0]; // grab first array element
    delete arr[i].d;     // delete d from object
    temp2 = arr[i].e[0]; // grab first array element
    delete arr[i].e;     // delete e from object

    output.push($.extend(arr[i], temp2)); // merge object and e, push
    output.push($.extend(temp1, temp2));  // merge d and e, push
  }
  return output; // move from in for loop to here
}
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {a:1,b:2,c:3,h:8}, {f:6,g:7,h:8}, 
  {a:1,b:2,c:3,h:8}, {f:6,g:7,h:8}, 
  {a:1,b:2,c:3,h:8}, {f:6,g:7,h:8}
]
```

[JSBin example.](http://jsbin.com/kihoval/edit?js,console)

You tagged jQuery, so it was used for the `extend` function. Plain JS, or smaller libraries are available for anyone not using jQuery.